# Laravel 5: Creating new models in controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What is the proper way to create new models in Laravel 5 controllers? I don't want to use models classes names directly, but inject them to controller's constructor instead, like this:

```
public function __construct(User $user) {
    $this->user = $user;
    // ...
}
```

To operate on the User model, I would normally use controller's property, like this:

```
$target = $this->user
               ->women()
               ->whereBetween('age', [18, 29])
               ->get();
```

But how can I create a new model using `$this->user`? Normally I prefer to use `new User;` and assign properties to then use `$user->save();`. But this way it's rather impossible, isn't it? I know there's `create()` method, which would work in this case, like this:

```
$girl = $this->user->create([
    'name' => 'Jessica Hottie',
    'age'  => 21
]);
```

But this way I'm losing possibility to use `associate()` method etc.

Do I need to use `create()` anyway, or maybe there's even better way to handle model dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
$girl = $this->user->newInstance($attributes); //this doesn't save the model yet
$girl->relation->associate($some_other_model);
$girl->save();
```